# in angular project I used show password. When i clicked on submit that icon is coming to down after checking the validation

Tags: angular

```
import { ShowHidePasswordModule } from 'ngx-show-hide-password';
```

I had imported the required modules like show pass hide password and I installed them in my project but when I am clicking on button it is validating the function and if not satisfied then that css is changed

These things I kept in xxx.component.html

```
<div class="form-group busipass">
  <label for="password"></label>

  <show-hide-password icon="fa-eye" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control 
   eyeicon Placeholder" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && 
   f.password.errors }" placeholder="Password"/>

    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback"> 
      <br>
      <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
    </div>
  </show-hide-password>``

</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
  <button (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary Rectangle-4" style="width:103%;">
    <p class="Login">Login</p>
  </button>          
</div>
```

css for the code

xxx.component.css

```
.busipass {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

How can I resolve this problem of getting css? Help me to overcome it.

Comment: have you imported this ` ShowHidePasswordModule.forRoot(),`

Comment: yeah I imported

Comment: can you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: Yeah Actually i had imported those necessary modules and i gave validations for that. Validations were working properly. But the thing is when I submit empty form that eye icon is coming to next line it is not in the same line. Means CSS for that icon is going to next line